# "Expression.Error: The field 'Project Name' already exists in the record" when using PowerBI data source: Visual Studio Team Services (Beta)

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

Our Team is leveraging PowerBI Desktop to extract data from VSTS, but after selecting several of the pre-built views, we receiving the following error:

> > Expression.Error: The field 'Project Name' already exists in the record.
> >     Details:
> >         Name=Project Name
> >         Value=

The error occurs for the following views:
 Stories - [All Views]
 Work Items - [All Views]

But does not appear when using the following views:
 Bugs - [All Views]
 Tasks - [All Views]

The error does not reveal much information as to what is causing the error.  Please help.

Comment: How did you specify the Account and Team project during connecting with VSTS? Can you provide related screen shots?

Comment: @Marina, for security reasons, I cannot share the account details (account or project name), but we did connect using the guidelines found here:  [PowerBi Data Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=vsts)

We see this same behavior on several of the connections (we have ~90 projects under this account).  

Would this error be related to customizations that were made to the Process templates?

Comment: So what's the step when the error occurred, when clicking connect button or when selecting a project etc? And what's the result if you connect with a VSTS account which has less projects?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT this error occurs within the PowerBI Desktop after we connect to the project.  When selecting the available views, the error is shown in the preview pane that occurs on the right side of the View Selection screen.  This is represented as Step #11 in the [Configuration Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=vsts)



We do not believe the issue is related to the # of projects.

Comment: So if you do not select any items, there has no error shows, and if you select any of a item (such as Work Items - Today), then the error occurs?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Yes.  If we do not select a View, no error is shown.  In order to pull the data into PowerBI, we need to select an item though.  Since this error occurs on all of the views pertaining to "All Items", we can not extract the data to render. Perhaps a screen sharing / Demo will assist?

Comment: For my own project, powerBI can show the preview for all items correctly (as the example https://ibb.co/ikk3Ty and https://ibb.co/g6D1Fd). And What if you restart PowerBI and reconnect to your VSTS team project?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT does your project have any process customizations?  We have restarted PowerBI.  What does this error mean?  `Expression.Error: The field 'Project Name' already exists in the record. Details: Name=Project Name Value=`

Comment: Yes, my project use inherited process template with new fields. How did you custom the work item user story? And what if you connect powerBI with another project which use the same process template?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same result if I add a field with field name `Project Name`.

And for VSTS, the field name `Project Name` is valid. More details, you can refer [Naming restrictions and conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/naming-restrictions?view=vsts#field-names-work-item-tracking) for field name.

While for PowerBI, since it already has a column `Project Name`, when it load the WIT with the custom field name `Project Name`, it will report the message:

[image]

> Expression.Error: The field 'Project Name' already exists in the
>   record

The workaround is you can custom a different field name such as `Project Name1` instead. Or you can [feedback](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas) the issue to PowerBI.